# Unable to get req.file.path

Tags: node.js, angular, express, mean-stack, multer

I am getting req.file getting response as below

```
{ fieldname: 'product_image',
  originalname: '71ELL0gnILL._UL1500_.jpg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  buffer: <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 ff db 00 43 00 05 03 04 04 04 03 05 04 04 04 05 05 05 06 07 0c 08 07 07 07 07 0f 0b 0b 09 ... >,
  size: 206437 }
```

but req.file.path I am getting undefined

This is form MEAN stack, I am uploading the file from client(Angular) and sending  it to the NODE but it's not working.

Any one please help me in this.

Comment: please provide some code and how you send the file

Comment: You need some multipart upload middleware to get `req.file`

Comment: I am uploading file from angular 4 by using one API I am sending it to the back-end I am getting req.file is fine But problem in path and I am using multer at node as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In its default configuration `multer` will keep the whole file in memory and therefore the path property doesn't exist, since a file path only ever makes sense for files that have been stored on a file system.

In order to have `multer` store uploaded files to disk, you have to pass an upload destination like so

```
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })
```

or pass a customized `DiskStorage` as [explained here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#diskstorage).

Comment: Thanks it's works for me you save my day